# Inner joining two tables from separate databases without duplicate

Tags: sql-server

Please look at the following query:

**tbl_EASY_INVOICECONTROLDB.dbo.impersonalaccount**

```
departmentname  accountid   accountname         accounttype
------------------------------------------------------------
Football Club   82425       Consultancy         G/L Account
Stadium Ltd     82425       Professional fees   G/L Account
```

**tbl_documents4.dbo.GLcodetable2**

```
username      item      department
------------------------------------------------------
RAY           82425     otrUserSettingsGLcodes_Stadium
RAY           82425     otrUserSettingsGLcodes
```

**Query**

```
SELECT     
    A.item, A.username,  A.department, 
    B.departmentname, B.accounttype, B.accountname
FROM         
    dbo.GLcodetable2 AS A 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    EASY_INVOICECONTROLDB.dbo.impersonalaccount AS B ON A.item = B.accountid
WHERE
    (A.item = '82425') AND (A.username = 'RAY')
```

**Result:**

```
item           username       department                        departmentname      accountype      accountname
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
82425          RAY        otrUserSettingsGLcodes                Football Club      G/L Account       Consultancy
82425          RAY        otrUserSettingsGLcodes_Stadium        Football Club      G/L Account       Consultancy      
82425          RAY        otrUserSettingsGLcodes                Stadium Ltd        G/L Account       Professional fees      
82425          RAY        otrUserSettingsGLcodes_Stadium        Stadium Ltd        G/L Account       Professional fees
```

Some lines of data are appearing twice.

I'm trying to join the two table together and obtain one result per department name.

I tried `GROUP BY` but that doesn't seem to work.

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**

The result I'm looking for is

```
item           username       department                        departmentname      accountype      accountname
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
82425          RAY        otrUserSettingsGLcodes                Football Club      G/L Account       Consultancy        
82425          RAY        otrUserSettingsGLcodes_Stadium        Stadium Ltd        G/L Account       Professional fees
```

Comment: As per your table structure output is correct, as your join table mean pk table has no unique id

Comment: There arn't any duplicates?  What do you want in the department column?  The results are different?

Comment: Please check all the columns values in each row. There is no duplicates in your result set. What would be your expected output.

Comment: I am trying to get the result to only show 2 lines. unique line per each departmentname: Football Club, Stadium Ltd. where the department is otrUserSettingsGLcodes_Stadium it should only come up in departmentname Stadium Ltd.

Comment: Ok, I see your update but it is entirely unclear how you come by the value for `department` - it is neither the first nor the last joined result. You need to describe the logic by which you select `otrUserSettingsGLcodes_Stadium` or `otrUserSettingsGLcodes` (or, simply leave out that column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need all the columns from two tables then you would get four records but if you get rid off department column then you would get two records based on department name. Try like this, I commented department column in your query.

```
SELECT      
A.item, 
A.username, 
--A.department, 
B.departmentname, 
B.accounttype, 
B.accountname

FROM         @GLcodetable2 AS A 
LEFT OUTER JOIN @impersonalaccount AS B ON A.item = B.accountid
WHERE     (A.item = '82425') AND (A.username = 'RAY')
group by A.item, 
A.username, 
--A.department, 
B.departmentname, 
B.accounttype, 
B.accountname
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the requirement you can check adding department in the join condition

```
ON A.ItemID = B.AccountID AND A.department = B.departmentName
```